# Characterization of coherent topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X_i, \tau_i)$ be topological spaces and $X = \bigcup_i X_i$. Let $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ such that the topologies $\tau_i$'s coincide with the subspace topologies on $X_i$ induced by $\tau$. I have to show that if each $X_i$ is open (respectively closed) in $X$, then
> $$
> \tau = \{A\subseteq X : A\cap X_i\in \tau_i\}\text.
> $$

I could show this when each $X_i$ is open in $X$, as follows:

"$\subseteq$": Let $A\in \tau$. Then $A\cap X_i$ is open in the subspace topology on $X_i$ which coincides wit $\tau_i$ and hence $A\cap X_i\in\tau_i$ for any $i$.

"$\supseteq$": Let $A$ be in RHS. Now, $A\cap X_i$ is open in $\tau_i$ and hence open in the subspace topology on $X_i$. Since $X_i$ is itself open in $X$, the open sets in $X_i$'s subspace topology are also open in $X$. Hence $A\cap X_i$ is open in $X$ as well. Now, $A = \bigcup_i(A\cap X_i)$ which is hence open in $X$.

**Question:** I can't seem to prove the "$\supseteq$'' direction when all of $X_i$'s are closed in $X$. Can you help?

Comment: If the $X_i$ form a locally finite family in $(X,\tau)$, then it is true in the closed case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true in the closed case.  For instance, suppose the $X_i$'s are just all the singletons in $X$.  Then the condition that the subspace topology on $X_i$ is the same as $\tau_i$ is automatic, and the conclusion would be saying an arbitrary $T_1$ topology $\tau$ on $X$ must be discrete.